# vba vlookup another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Anyone knows how to fix those code? Run-Time error '1004':Application-defined or object-defined error

I changed my code as below.. still doesn't work..

```
 Sub Testing()

    Dim DRACCT As String
    Dim DR24 As Variant
    Dim sh1, sh2 As Workbook
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Lastrow = Range("A10000000").End(xlUp).Row

    Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    'On Error Resume Next

    For i = 2 To Lastrow

        DRACCT = sh1.Cells(i, 66).Value
        DR24 = Application.VLookup(DRACCT, sh2.Range("A:B"), 2, False)

        If Not IsError(DR24) Then
        sh1.Cells(i, 68).Value = DR24

        Else ' do nothing
        End If

    Next i


    End Sub
```

Comment: I will bet that the value is not found in the lookup range.  If that happens it stops the code.  There are many ways to deal with such error outlined in answers on this site.  here is one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21468369/getting-application-defined-or-object-defined-error

Comment: Here is another: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063214/how-to-error-handle-1004-error-with-worksheetfunction-vlookup

Comment: And `Dim i As Long` not as `Integer` if you want to use it as a counter up-to `LastRow` which is typed `Long`.

Comment: I tried Dim i As Long.. it doesn't help..

Comment: You missed a step, if you are going that route you must use `Application.VLookup` not `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup`

Comment: still Run-Time error '1004':Application-defined or object-defined error .. Maybe other problem? @scottcraner

Comment: On what line, up date the code.

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: I used `Application.Vlookup` instead of `Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems

1. there are only `1045876` rows not `10000000` this is your current error.
2. the next error you will get is because you are trying to set a worksheet to a workbook variable

The Code

```
Sub Testing()

Dim DRACCT As String
Dim DR24 As Variant
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long

Lastrow = Range("A1046876").End(xlUp).Row

Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

'On Error Resume Next

For i = 2 To Lastrow

    DRACCT = sh1.Cells(i, 66).Value
    DR24 = Application.VLookup(DRACCT, sh2.Range("A:B"), 2, False)

    If Not IsError(DR24) Then
    sh1.Cells(i, 68).Value = DR24

    Else ' do nothing
    End If

Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: >< silly me.. I read the sample you gave me before.. forget to consider this. Thank you Scott! so 1045876 is max row for excel sheet??

Comment: Yes, if this worked, please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.